# IBM-MQ (ibm.mq.allclient:jar:9.2.2.0) Spring Boot dynamic listener fails with too many MQ connections with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason 2537

Tags: spring-boot, listener, ibm-mq, spring-jms

```
Error : MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2537' ('MQRC_CHANNEL_NOT_AVAILABLE')
```

Start-up of the application we fetch the queue name dynamically and create a JMS listener programmatically. Messages are processed within the transaction and if the transaction fails it rolls back to the IBM-MQ queue

```java
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory mqJmsListenerContainerFactory() throws JMSException {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(ibmConnectionFactory);
    factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    factory.setConcurrency(requestConcurrency);
    return factory;
}
```

```
for (IBMmqQueue aTradeQueue : requestMQQueueNames) {//we have dynamic queue names
    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(aTradeQueue.getTradeRequestName())){
        continue;
    }
    SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint endpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
    endpoint.setId(aTradeQueue.getTradeRequestName());
    endpoint.setDestination(aTradeQueue.getTradeRequestName());
    endpoint.setMessageListener(message -> {
        TransactionStatus status = jmsTransactionManager.getTransaction(null);
        try {
            // This starts a new transaction scope. "null" can be used to get a default transaction model
            ibmmqConsumer.tradeListener(message, aTradeQueue.getTradeRequestName());
            jmsTransactionManager.commit(status);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            jmsTransactionManager.rollback(status);
            try {
                LOG.error("Failed to publish to Active-MQ & rolled back to IBM-MQ : " + message.getJMSMessageID());
            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    try {
        registrar.setContainerFactory(this.mqJmsListenerContainerFactory());
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the queue manager logs and this link https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/8.0?topic=codes-2537-09e9-rc2537-mqrc-channel-not-available

Comment: it has connected and fetched records from the queue, over period of time connections are exhausted which makes mq to fail channel manager

Comment: That indicates your application is not closing connections to queue manager correctly. It appears that your application opens a connection, opens a queue, gets message but is NOT closing connection. This makes channel instances to exhaust leading 2537 reason code. Check your application code and modify to close queue and connection once job is done.

Comment: Rule # 1 in programming, if you open it, make sure you close it.  The same applies to queue manager connections.  If you connect to it then make sure under ALL circumstances (regular or error condition) that the connection is closed.  As @Shashi said, your application is not closing the connection, hence, it is consuming all of the connections to the queue manager.

Comment: Spring should be handling the opening and closing of your connections. Though I don't see anywhere in your code where you link the connection to the transaction manager, so I don't think your commit or rollback do anything related to the connection. Hence keeping it open.

Comment: If you have `setSessionTransacted(true)` then spring should be handling the transaction. Your `OnMessage` method signals a rollback by throwing an exception, else its a commit. You don't need `TransactionStatus status` etc. and it might be that that is consuming your connections.

Comment: we use spring boot and spring boot manages the open / close. What we see it goes the channel open the conversation (default 10) once it consumed then creates another connection (default conversation 10), and move on.